# Is there a way to do a msqyl select, insert, update without a php script

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, orders and details. We have an issue with very old details where orders were not created for them and we have to create dummy orders for them to work properly. My goal is if a detail doesn't have an order, create one and set net to 0.00, and put the incremental order id created into details. Is the following scenario possible in a mysql script to update ALL details with new orders if their order column is NULL? Or do I have to use a back-end language like PHP to make this possible. I'd prefer to keep it MySql only.

**Pre-Script Table Example:**

```
Order Table
ID   Net
1    19.95
2    9.95

Details Table
ID   Order
1    1
2    1
3    3
4    NULL
5    NULL
```

**Post-Script Table Example:**

```
Order Table
ID   Net
1    19.95
2    9.95
3    0.00
4    0.00

Details Table
ID   Order
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    4
```

Comment: The `3 | 2` bit looks like a bad idea !?! Anyway, why does it matter if the orders are missing?

Comment: Order as in a Purchase Order not sort order

Comment: Yes. That's the only kind of order we're talking about here.